# Listview Filter with PJAX in Yii2 not working

Tags: listview, yii2, pjax

I have set a filter for some parameters on a listview. The filter is working but the entire page is reload, even if I use Pjax. I even tried to increase pjax timeout without success.

Here is the controller:

```
public function actionArticles()
{
    $articleSearch = new ArticleSearch();
    $articleDataProvider = $articleSearch ->search(Yii::$app->request->post());

    return $this->render('list', ['articleSearch ' => $articleSearch ,
                                     'articleDataProvider ' => $articleDataProvider ]);
}
```

Here is the view:

```
<?php Pjax::begin(['id' => 'pjax_list_articles', 
                   'timeout' => false, 
                   'clientOptions' => ['method' => 'POST']]); ?> 

<?php $mapCategories = ArrayHelper::map(Category::find()->orderby('cName ASC')->all(); ?>

<div class="filter_form">   

<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'id' => 'search_form',
    'method' => 'post',
    'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
    'enableClientValidation'=>false,
    'options' => ['class' => 'form-horizontal'], 
]); ?>

    <?= $form->field($articleSearch , 'aCategory')
            ->dropDownList( $mapCategories ,'cID', 'cName'), 
                        ['prompt'=> Yii::t('app', 'All categories'), 
                         'onchange'=>'this.form.submit()'
                        ] )
            ->label(false) 
    ?>  

<?php ActiveForm::end() ?>  

</div>


<div class="listView_container">

    <?= 
        ListView::widget([

            'dataProvider' => $articleDataProvider ,

            'layout' => "{items}\n{pager}",

            'itemView' => function ($model, $key, $index, $widget) {
                return $this->render('_article_view',['model' => $model]);
            },

            'pager' => [
                        'firstPageLabel' => Yii::t('main','first'),
                        'lastPageLabel' => Yii::t('main','last'),
                        'prevPageLabel' => Yii::t('main','previous'),
                        'nextPageLabel' => Yii::t('main','next'),
                        'maxButtonCount' => 3,
                    ],

            'emptyText' => $emptyText,

        ]);
    ?>

</div>

<?php Pjax::end(); ?>
```

The filter is working but reload the entire page. 
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't see any problem in your code except timeout 'false'. did you try increasing it to about 5000? Please use developer tools network tab and click 'preserve logs'. you will get clues on why the request failed

Comment: After looking deep I found that the problem is coming from `'onchange'=>'this.form.submit()'`. When i use a **submitButton** it s working fine.

Comment: that's great! So your problem is resolved?

Comment: No, it s not resolved. I m using the **submitButton** now for this to work. But it would be better for my case to submit the form after **onchange event**.